# Team Explorer Everywhere (command line) lying?

Tags: command-line, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm trying to get some code pulled down from a local TFS server onto my Mac.  I've been fussing around with TEE for quite some time now and it seems it doesn't keep track of what I'm doing from one command to the next.  I set a working folder, then try to to perform a `get`, and I'm met with odd messages:

```
GA8995AC511228:TEE-CLC-10.0.0 rr154459$ ./tf dir ../all -server:http://10.227.212.202:8080/tfs -login:rr154459@na
There is no working folder mapping for /Users/rr154459/tfs/all.
GA8995AC511228:TEE-CLC-10.0.0 rr154459$ ./tf workfold -map -login:rr154459@na -server:http://10.227.212.202:8080/tfs -workspace:GA8995AC511228 '$\' '../all'
An error occurred: The new working folder mapping of $\ to /Users/rr154459/tfs/all conflicts with the local path in the existing mapping of $/ to /Users/rr154459/tfs/all.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$\` is not a server path.  You need to use `$/`.

Please remove your existing workspace mappings and set them using the correct path formatting.

Comment: I have deleted my workspace, created a new one using `./tf workspace -new -server:http://10.227.212.202:8080/tfs`, and mapped a work folder with `./tf workfold -map -login:user@domain -server:http://10.227.212.202:8080/tfs -workspace:GA8995AC511228 '$/DefaultCollection/project' '../project'`.  When I try a `get`, it tells me `Items must reside in a workspace that has been previously used on this computer.`.